# jQuery - Toggle .active class between 3 div cousins

Tags: jquery, toggleclass

I'd like to toggle .test-active class between any of the 3 divs that currently have .section-resources as a class. Only one div should have .test-active at a time.

as it is .test-active is being added to all 3 divs.

any help is appreciated and sorry for the noobness, its my first post. :P

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.section-resources').click(function(e) {
      if ($('this').not('.test-active')) {
        $('.section-resources').addClass('test-active');
      } else if ($('.section-resources').hasClass('test-active')) {
        $('this').removeClass('test-active');
      } else {
        $('this').addClass('test-active');
      }
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.test-active {
  border: 1px solid #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="frame">
  <div>
    <a href="#!">some link</a>
    <div class="section-resources"><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a> 
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#!">some link</a>
      <div class="section-resources"><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a> 
      </div>
      <div>
        <a href="#!">some link</a>
        <div class="section-resources"><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sitamet</a> 
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.section-resources').click(function(target) {
        $('.section-resources').removeClass('test-active');
        $(target).addClass('test-active');
      target.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll be trying this this and post results soon! :D